# interval in python

Tags: python, list, datetime, intervals

I have sorted list of datetime.time and want to create intervals like. If I have

```
a = [datetime.time(0,0), datetime.time(8,0), datetime.time(13,0), datetime.time(17,0)]
```

Then result should be like this:

```
c = [[datetime.time(0,0),datetime.time(8,0)], [datetime.time(8,0),datetime.time(13,0)],
[datetime.time(13,0),datetime.time(17,0)], [datetime.time(17,0),datetime.time(0,0)]]
```

This could be achieved using simple loop but if there is better solution exist?

**Using loop:**

```
>>> a=[datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(3, 0), datetime.time(8, 0), datetime.time(11, 0)]
>>> 
>>> r = []
>>> 
>>> for i in range(0,len(a)):
...     if i+1 < len(a):
...         r.append([a[i],a[i+1]])
...     else:
...         r.append([a[i],a[0]])
... 
>>> r
[[datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(3, 0)], [datetime.time(3, 0), datetime.time(8, 0)], [datetime.time(8, 0), datetime.time(11, 0)], [datetime.time(11, 0), datetime.time(0, 0)]]
>>>
```

nd what could be change if I want result to be

```
[[datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(2, 59, 59)], [datetime.time(3, 0), datetime.time(7, 59, 59)], [datetime.time(8, 0), datetime.time(10, 59, 59)], [datetime.time(11, 0), datetime.time(23, 59, 59)]]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try

```
a = list(zip(a[:-1], a[1:]))
a.append((a[-1], a[0])])
```

That gives you a list of tuples. If you want a list of lists, just do

```
>>> a = [list(i) for i in zip(a[:-1], a[1:])]
>>> a.append([a[-1], a[0]])
```

(*Edited version taking 1. the `[a[-1],a[0]]` out of the list comprehension and 2. the fact that zip doesn't return a list in Python 3+*)

Yet another possibility would be to just append the first value to the list:

```
>>> tmp = a + a[0]
>>> list(zip(tmp[:,-1], tmp[1:]))
```

It can be argued that it creates a temporary list. You could do a`a.append(a[0])` instead but then you'd modify your initial list, which might be an issue.

Comment: Although, I would probably `a.append` the last element outside of the list comprehension for 2 reasons:  1) `zip` doesn't return a list in py3k. (and I don't think `2to3` would handle this properly) 2) concatenation creates a new list which is unnecessary here.

Comment: @PierreGM One thing you could do is `a.append(a[0])` before the `zip`-ing. Then your list comprehension for the zip will have the first elem + last pair.

Comment: @aneroid : edited to take your suggestion into account, with a warning.

Comment: @PierreGM Yes, was going to mention that warning too :-)

Comment: and what could be change if I want result to be [[datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(2, 59, 59)], [datetime.time(3, 0), datetime.time(7, 59, 59)], [datetime.time(8, 0), datetime.time(10, 59, 59)], [datetime.time(11, 0), datetime.time(23, 59, 59)]]

Comment: Once you have your intervals, just remove `dt=datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)` from the second member: `[(i,j-dt) for (i,j) in your_intervals]`

Comment: +1 for the ["zip inspiration"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12389330/1431750) :-) Did not think of using zip instead of list comp. Next step: use `timeit` to benchmark all! :P j/k

Answer (score 5):

For creating a range like this, I might try a generator:

```
def make_ranges(lst):
    max_idx = len(lst) - 1
    for i,item in enumerate(lst):
        yield [item, lst[i+1 if i != max_idx else 0] ]
```

You could play around with keyword arguments to tell `make_ranges` whether or not to be periodic and if periodic, whether or not to include the wraparound at the beginning or the end.

Then you can make your ranges:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
b = list(make_ranges(a))
print(b == [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6],[6,7],[7,8],[8,1]]) #True
```

Answer (score 3):

One more option<sup>1</sup> as a one-liner: but with a **really unpythonic expression** (imho) so that you don't have to append the last and first pair in a separate step:

```
>>> [list(i) for i in zip(a, a[1:]+[a[0]])]
[[datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(8, 0)],
 [datetime.time(8, 0), datetime.time(13, 0)],
 [datetime.time(13, 0), datetime.time(17, 0)],
 [datetime.time(17, 0), datetime.time(0, 0)]]
```

<sup>1</sup> `zip` method [inspired by Pierre-GM's solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12388054/1431750).

FYI, **I prefer either [my initial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12388105/1431750) or Pierre's** over this.

---

Edit/Update for 2nd part of the question: To do the timedeltas in one expression also (but I see no good reason why this shouldn't just be **split out into different statements** instead...):

```
>>> [[i, (datetime.datetime(101, 1, 1, j.hour, j.minute, j.second) -
...       datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
...      ).time()
...  ] for i,j in zip(a, a[1:]+[a[0]])
... ]
[[datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(7, 59, 59)],
 [datetime.time(8, 0), datetime.time(12, 59, 59)],
 [datetime.time(13, 0), datetime.time(16, 59, 59)],
 [datetime.time(17, 0), datetime.time(23, 59, 59)]]
```

Comment: Till you're at it, you could subtract 1s from the second member of each element to solve the second part of the question...

Comment: @PierreGM lol, done. That's 20 minutes I'll never get back :P

Comment: @sharafjaffri There's the answer to the 2nd part of your question.

Answer (score 2):

How about a list comprehension if not a 'simple loop'? Like:

```
>>> b = [[a[x], a[x+1]] for x in range(0, len(a)-1)] + [[a[-1], a[0]]]
>>> b
[[datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(8, 0)],
 [datetime.time(8, 0), datetime.time(13, 0)],
 [datetime.time(13, 0), datetime.time(17, 0)],
 [datetime.time(17, 0), datetime.time(0, 0)]]
```

Comment: that's using loop but didn't work with paring of last and first item look as last value in my projected list.

Comment: Last and First pairing at the end has to be manually added, even with @pierre-gm's method. List comprehensions aren't just Loops even though they use loops. And this list comprehension is better than the loop in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **more_itertools** library which is a recipe code around the python standard library **itertools**.
If you want to process elements while iterating:

```
import more_itertools as more
rv = [(x, y) for (x, y) in more.pairwise(a)]
```

or simply:

```
rv = list(more.pairwise(a))
```

Also as stated before is an answer, zip is also a good choice:

```
rv = list(zip(a[:-1], a[1:]))
```